# Why does react throw error cannot read property of undefined?

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and i get this error.

"cannot read property on_cancel of undefined"

I am retreiving this on_cancel method as a prop from parent to child component.

before calling this method on_cancel i check if it is defined. In doing so, i still get cannot read property on_cancel of undefined error.

How can i fix it.

Below is my code,

```
class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
   on_close_render = () => {
       global.ParentComponent.on_cancel && 
       global.ParentComponent.on_cancel()
    }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow `global.ParentComponent` is undefined you need to check if `global.ParentComponent` is defined before calling `on_cancel `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this below, this will check if global.ParentComponent is undefined. And if not, it will proceed on executing global.ParentComponent.on_cancel()

`global.ParentComponent && 
global.ParentComponent.on_cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

ParentComponent seems to be undefined as well. Can you once verify that ParentComponent is present?